# How to send email notification using Cloud Pubsub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, email-notifications

How to send email notification from Pub sub using python script when files are uploaded in google cloud compute engine.

Answer (score 1):

### The following examples illustrate the creation of notification channels with Python

```
def restore(project_name, backup_filename):
    print(
        "Loading alert policies and notification channels from {}.".format(
            backup_filename
        )
    )
    record = json.load(open(backup_filename, "rt"))
    is_same_project = project_name == record["project_name"]
    # Convert dicts to AlertPolicies.
    policies_json = [json.dumps(policy) for policy in record["policies"]]
    policies = [
        monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy.from_json(policy_json)
        for policy_json in policies_json
    ]
    # Convert dicts to NotificationChannels
    channels_json = [json.dumps(channel) for channel in record["channels"]]
    channels = [
        monitoring_v3.NotificationChannel.from_json(channel_json)
        for channel_json in channels_json
    ]

    # Restore the channels.
    channel_client = monitoring_v3.NotificationChannelServiceClient()
    channel_name_map = {}

    for channel in channels:
        updated = False
        print("Updating channel", channel.display_name)
        # This field is immutable and it is illegal to specify a
        # non-default value (UNVERIFIED or VERIFIED) in the
        # Create() or Update() operations.
        channel.verification_status = (
            monitoring_v3.NotificationChannel.VerificationStatus.VERIFICATION_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED
        )

        if is_same_project:
            try:
                channel_client.update_notification_channel(notification_channel=channel)
                updated = True
            except google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound:
                pass  # The channel was deleted.  Create it below.

        if not updated:
            # The channel no longer exists.  Recreate it.
            old_name = channel.name
            del channel.name
            new_channel = channel_client.create_notification_channel(
                name=project_name, notification_channel=channel
            )
            channel_name_map[old_name] = new_channel.name

    # Restore the alerts
    alert_client = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicyServiceClient()

    for policy in policies:
        print("Updating policy", policy.display_name)
        # These two fields cannot be set directly, so clear them.
        del policy.creation_record
        del policy.mutation_record

        # Update old channel names with new channel names.
        for i, channel in enumerate(policy.notification_channels):
            new_channel = channel_name_map.get(channel)
            if new_channel:
                policy.notification_channels[i] = new_channel

        updated = False

        if is_same_project:
            try:
                alert_client.update_alert_policy(alert_policy=policy)
                updated = True
            except google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound:
                pass  # The policy was deleted.  Create it below.
            except google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument:
                # Annoying that API throws InvalidArgument when the policy
                # does not exist.  Seems like it should throw NotFound.
                pass  # The policy was deleted.  Create it below.

        if not updated:
            # The policy no longer exists.  Recreate it.
            old_name = policy.name
            del policy.name
            for condition in policy.conditions:
                del condition.name
            policy = alert_client.create_alert_policy(
                name=project_name, alert_policy=policy
            )
        print("Updated", policy.name)
```

For more information I recommend you read the following documentation about [Managing notification channels by API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-channels-api#ncd)

**This product or feature is covered by the Pre-GA Offerings Terms of the Google Cloud Terms of Service. Pre-GA products and features might have limited support, and changes to pre-GA products and features might not be compatible with other pre-GA versions. For more information, see the launch stage descriptions.**

Additionally You want to check this information about [Setting up a messaging app](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-enable-real-time-notifications#setting_up_a_messaging_app) this describes how to use Pub/Sub and Cloud Functions to enable near real-time notifications for SendGrid Email API, Slack, and WebEx Teams